# Azure Data Factory: Deduplicate array

Tags: arrays, duplicates, azure-data-factory

I have an Azure Data Factory pipeline with an array as parameter with potentially duplicate (simple string) values.

How can I remove the duplicates from the array without using a custom activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I defined a variable of type `array` and applied a union on the parameter itself. This removes the duplicate values.

Like `@union(pipeline().parameters.FilePaths,pipeline().parameters.FilePaths)`.